# How to redirect requests for .php files to PHP-FPM for all virtual hosts in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache2, php

In [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) forward all request that point to phisical .php file to [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/) is as follow:

LoadModule [fastcgi_module](http://www.fastcgi.com/) modules/mod_fastcgi.so

```
FastCGIExternalServer /usr/sbin/php-fpm -socket /usr/local/php/lib/php.sock -idle-timeout 900
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
Action php-fastcgi /usr/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi
ScriptAlias /usr/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi /usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

But in [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) is different, I'm following the tutorial in [Apache Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) but I don't understand as enable PHP for all virtual host, not each one.

I search in PHP documentation, there is not mention about install on Apache 2.4:

- [Install PHP on Apache 2.x on Unix systems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)
- [PHP-FPM
  Install](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.install.php)
- [PHP-FPM Documentation](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Documentation)

Only for mention, the soluction thank to +Diemuzi was:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.shtml index.cgi index.html index.htm
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/lib/php/php.sock  -idle-timeout 900 -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please share solution.

Comment: @Nullpointer Read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you out. This is my working configuration(s) for setting up Apache 2.4 / mod_fastcgi / PHP-FPM -> https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/3849349